# Send the file and the filename using Python

Tags: python, sockets

I want to make a dead simple server that accepts different types of files from clients. The problem is, that I cannot get the filename sent over from the client, so all the files are saved as 1 filename, whatever the file is called.

This is my client.py:

```
import socket
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('192.168.1.2',10000))
    with open('Image.jpg','rb') as f:
        s.sendall(f.read())
```

And this is my server.py:

```
import socket
print("Server started")
while True:
        with socket.socket() as s:
            s.bind(('192.168.1.2',10000))
            s.listen(1)
            with s.accept()[0] as c:
                chunks = []
                while True:
                    chunk = c.recv(4096)
                    if not chunk: break
                    chunks.append(chunk)
                    print("Receiving file")
            with open('Image.jpg','wb') as f:
                f.write(b''.join(chunks))
                print("File Received")
```

Which works fine. The problem starts, that if I send another file, for example "data.csv" it will still be saved as "Image.jpg" on the server.

Is there any way to also save the filename along with the file?

Comment: Maybe you could include it as a header, or as a message before the picture?

Comment: Sending files in clear text isn't a great idea nowadays, have you considered using `scp` ?

Comment: You'll need to create a wire protocol that lets you include the file name (or use one that already can do so, like e.g. ftp...)

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do is send the filename before the data:

```
import socket
print("Server started")
while True:
        with socket.socket() as s:
            s.bind(('192.168.1.2',10000))
            s.listen(1)
            with s.accept()[0] as c:
                chunks = []
                while True:
                    filename = c.recv(1600)
                    filename = filename.decode()
                    chunk = c.recv(4096)
                    if not chunk: break
                    chunks.append(chunk)
                    print("Receiving file")
            with open(filename,'wb') as f:
                f.write(b''.join(chunks))
                print("File Received")
```

Client:

```
import socket
import time
with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('192.168.1.2',10000))
    with open('Image.jpg','rb') as f:
        s.sendall('Image.jpg'.encode())
        time.sleep(3)
        s.sendall(f.read())
```